# how to write the validation rule for the below code

Tags: validation, validation-rule

```
if(advance__c !=null){
  amount__c + Tax_Amount__c;
}
else{
  (amount__c + Tax_Amount__c)-advance__c;
}
```

Comment: What exactly you are looking for?

Comment: Do you mean a formula field ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for a formula field.
Create a formula field of type number and use this formula

IF(ISNULL( advance__c ) , (amount__c + Tax_Amount__c)-advance__c, amount__c + Tax_Amount__c)

Answer (score 0):

`amount__c + Tax_Amount__c - NULLVALUE(advance__c, 0)`